# Is it normal that Hudson takes an awful lot of time before he notices a new SVN revision?

Tags: svn, hudson

I just recently started using Hudson as a CI server for a project of mine. I've set up a "job" with a SVN-repository. The server runs on my local machine and the SVN repository is hosted at http://www.unfuddle.com.

The problem is that when I commit the code from my local machine and then manually trigger a build in Hudson that it takes several minutes before the new revision is detected. So the first build after a commit is always a build without using the new revision.

Is this normal? Is there any setting to prevent this behaviour?

Thanks in advance and best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose when you trigger the build it performs an update and logs a messegs like "At revision xxx" but without any changes

I have seen this effect when the Subversion server's and the Hudson server's clock were out of sync. Hudson actually logs this as a warning during the build if it is the case. I don't know why, but when the clock is out of sync, the update performs strangely.

Comment: Mhh after your hint I looked up the commit times in my SVN log and the time that Hudson uses and there are several minutes difference. Don't ask me why. 

That seems to be the root of the problem. Now it is just a matter of how to fix it.

Comment: Mhh ok I found out that my PC clock was ~3 minutes behind. Now that I've fixed that everything works as it should.

Comment: Another reason to switch from Subversion to Mercurial ;)